# python | I have json file : contains dictionaries inside some keys list and this list contains a dictionary

Tags: python

python | I have json file : contains dictionaries inside some keys list and this list contains a dictionary , how to loop through the last dictionary

```
"5810897312302632": {
        "post_id": "5810897312302632",
        "comments":"[{'comment_id': '9359,'comment_text':'bla bla bla'}]
}
```

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73915928/edit) your post, It looks like there are some quotes not closed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for i in my_dictionary["5810897312302632"]["comments"]:
    print(i)
```

It will loop over `comments`.

Be aware that I named your dictionary as "my_dictionary".

Edit:
I create your dictionary like this:

```
inside_dictionary = {}
inside_dictionary["comment_id"] = '9359'
inside_dictionary["comment_text"] = 'bla bla bla'

my_dictionary = {}
my_dictionary["5810897312302632"] = {}
my_dictionary["5810897312302632"]["post_id"] = "5810897312302632"
my_dictionary["5810897312302632"]["comments"] = [inside_dictionary]
```

Comment: it's reading the last list as string so your code retrieved "["